# How to save pc's time in a PHP variable

Tags: php, javascript

How should I save the pc's time (not server time) in a PHP variable?
I tried

```
$a='<script type="text/javascript"> document.write(Date()) </script>';
```

without luck

Comment: What do you mean by saving the pc's time?

Comment: PHP server side. So it can't get the users time.

Comment: @Bondye I have changed my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to do that would be to send it to the PHP script via a form or query. All the PHP is executed on the server and sent out to whoever requested it. The PC time would have to be sent back to the server for it to know what it is.

Edit: If you want to just use javascript to show the current PC time you can echo out this in your code:

```
<script language="javascript">
<!--
  var today = new Date();
  document.write(today);
//-->
</script>
```

In PHP it would be:

```
$timeString='

<script language="javascript">
<!--
  var today = new Date();
  document.write(today);
//-->
</script>
';
echo $timeString;
```

It would show up as *Thu Jul 26 2012 00:17:43 GMT+1000 (EST)* on the client PC. Here is a link to a [decent tutorial](http://www.quackit.com/javascript/tutorial/javascript_date_and_time.cfm) on how to use javascript to display dates, times and all sorts of other goodies based on the users PC.

Edit 2: This Javascript will display the date and time nicely.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var d = new Date();
var curr_date = d.getDate();
var curr_month = d.getMonth();
curr_month++;
var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
var curr_hour = d.getHours();
var curr_min = d.getMinutes();
document.write(curr_month + "/" + curr_date + "/" + curr_year + " - " + curr_hour + ":" + curr_min);
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: Great, thank you for this. I have accepted your answer because of your help, but can you take a look at my newest edit ?

Comment: @Kaoukkos Found some nice javascript and added it to the answer, and on that note - heading to bed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use ajax on the client side to send your server side code the date. The server could then do what it needs and send updated information back to the server side, also via ajax. That is about the only way your server side code can get its hand on the client dateTime without a postback.

Hpoe that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I would use the javascript Date object (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) to grab the date from the client's machine, then pass it to a php script via AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned you could do this with AJAX. But a more important question is can you trust the clients date/time and why do you need the time/date on the clients machine? Besides you will not get an accurate time due to the load on your server, their client and the network in between.

Would it be better just to trust the time/date on your server? Just make a note of the time zone instead and perform the correction based upon that.